# Formula for a field

Tags: formula, formula-field, contact

How can I create the following formula field (with API name **Username**) on Contact?

First letter of **FirstName** + **LastName** + Number, such that if the combination is not unique, the number would make it unique.

For example, if I have a contact with **FirstName** being equal `John` and **LastName** being equal `Parker` the **Username** would be equal `JParker` then.

And if I will add a contact `James` `Parker` later on its **Username** would be `JParker1` (given that there were no Contact with the **FirstName** starting with the letter `J` and **LastName** `Parker` added between).

Is it a good idea to use a formula field for **Username** at all? If so, how could I create such a field?

Thank you.

And I would like to preserve the number at the end of **Username** (e.g. if I delete `JParker`, the `JParker1` should not change to `JParker`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a formula field. It's really a variant of the common "filtered autonumber" problem, where there's a desire to put an incrementing number after some field, but have multiple sequences running in parallel.

One approach is to use a List Custom Setting. You'd populate one instance of the custom setting for each first initial + last name combination that's created, and store the most recent digit used in that instance.

You'd need to write a `before insert` trigger, which would (for each inbound Contact) look up the Custom Setting for the desired username, using a `FOR UPDATE` query to lock that record. If the custom setting instance weren't found, you'd know that the user name had not been utilized before, and insert a new instance to record that it's been taken. If it were found, you'd increment the number stored there, use it in the username for the current Contact, and update the Custom Setting.

You'd also need to include some logic to handle, for example, the situation where two users with the same first initial and last name are inserted in the same transaction, and ensure that your queries are bulkified appropriately.

Comment: What do you mean by a `FOR UPDATE` query?

Comment: A lock to [prevent race conditions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm).